# debug grails application in eclipse IDE

Tags: grails

i want to debug Grails application in the eclipse kepler,i tried Debug As in eclipse and added break points but it runs normally as it in normal run mode ,  how i do that ?
Thanks

Comment: try to create "remote" in eclipse to listen port 5005 of localhost and run grails-debug from console

Answer (score 1):

**Burt's** answer from [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-to-debug-in-STS-td1578797.html)

> You can start a Grails app (one that has an Eclipse Grails nature,
>   i.e. it was created in STS or was converted via Configure | Convert to
>   Grails Project) in STS in debug mode using Run | Debug As | Grails
>   Command (run-app)
>
> You can also attach to any app that you start from the commandline via
>   "grails-debug run-app" by creating a Debug Configuration. Go to Run |
>   Debug Configurations and select Remote Java Application. Click the
>   'New' button or right-click the Remote Java Application node and
>   select New. Select the project that you're debugging and give the
>   configuration a meaningful name (I usually call them "attach
>   "). Change the port from 8000 to 5005, and I always check
>   the "Allow termination of remote VM" checkbox so I can kill the app
>   from the IDE, but that's optional. Click Debug and it'll attach. Note
>   that this will work for any Grails project that's in your workspace,
>   not just ones that have a Grails nature.
>
> Burt

Comment: i tried the first part , still going on the normal mode , the second part giving me this error : Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect

Comment: made it as you mentioned 5005

Comment: any ideas for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

in order to allow eclipse or any other debugger to connect to an external grails app running you need to start grails in debug mode:

grails-debug run-app

Doing this grails has to pause and wait for a remote debugger to connect.

Answer (score 1):

The grails-debug appears to be deprecated. Nowadays use:

```
grails --debug-fork run-app
```